# Limit the number of cards in cards deck in Bootstrap-vue

Tags: vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

I wanted to limit the number of cards per row to 4 but the cards keep getting squished to about 10+ cards per row.I tried to use bootstrap container but they didnt work out.

```
<b-container >
<b-row align-v = "center" order-xl>
<b-card-group deck>
<b-card v-for= "ids in info" v-bind:key="ids"
:title="ids.name"
:img-src="ids.images.xs" 
style="max-width: 20rem;"
min-cols = 3   
>
<b-card-text>
  <h5>

.....
 </h5>
</b-card-text>
</b-card>
</b-card-group >
</b-row>
</b-container>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set a min-width property to the cards:

```
<b-card v-for= "ids in info" v-bind:key="ids"
:title="ids.name"
:img-src="ids.images.xs" 
style="max-width: 20rem;"
class="mw-25"
min-cols = 3   
>
<b-card-text>
  <h5>

.....
 </h5>
</b-card-text>
</b-card>
```

`mw-25` is a bootstrap class that sets the min-widht to 25%.